# Is there any general WindowsFormApp event listener?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any WindowsFormApp listener method that automatically monitors events from child elements?
Clicking a button, opening a list, etc... without each one having its own method?

I'm trying to automate the event process bound to WindowsFormApp components. Example:
There are 10 buttons and I want a single method to monitor the actions of those 10 buttons or any other contained element. I already tried the manual method said at [Set the handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-6.0#set-the-handler). I want to know if there is an automated way, that is, some method of WindowsFormApp that is able to identify these events.

I await reply..

Thank you!

Comment: No, but you can multiply-select all the buttons in the designer and then in the properties select the desired event and enter the name of the method you want to handle it - then it will add that event handler for each of the selected buttons without further typing. (It will add an empty handler for which you still need to write the code, of course.)

Comment: You can implement [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) in a Form to handle all *events* (messages) for any Control in that Form. The `[Message].HWnd` property tells you which Control that message is directed to. You can handle it, suppress it or just let it through

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may add Event Handlers dynamically to ensure that they are the same for all children.

```
Panel p = new();
Button a = new();
Button b = new();

p.Controls.Add(a);
p.Controls.Add(b);
foreach (Button button in p.Controls) button.Click += Button_Click;

void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((Button)sender).Text = "I was clicked";
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem partially because I tested only for buttons, I will try to assimilate for several other elements.

Answer (score 0):

All very well!

I applied the following snippet to define the Click event of any element that has this action.

```
foreach (Control grandChild in this.Controls) grandChild.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Handle_events);

    private void Handle_events(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(sender);

        }
```